# http://localhost:8000/ is not showing any components even though I ran npm dev run

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new with React and I was trying to integrate it to my django backend. I followed two different tutorials that were quite similar but I got the same result, when I type "npm run dev", the only thing I see in my localhost is the title I changed in the html file and not the components I added on the App.js (not even the h1 tag that I'm showing here).
How can I fix this?

This is the App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";

export class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            
                <h1> View </h1>
            
        )
    }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

This the webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "reac": "*",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.36.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

This is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Forum</title>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{%static "css/index.css" %}"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="app"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what the terminal shows:

```
npm run dev

> frontend@1.0.0 dev
> webpack --mode development --watch

asset main.js 1010 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 974 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 26.3 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/*.js 412 bytes 2 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/*.js 25.9 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 70.6 KiB
    ./node_modules/react/index.js 190 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js 70.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 875 KiB
    ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 1.33 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js 874 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/object-assign/index.js 2.06 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/ 436 bytes
  ./src/index.js 35 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/components/App.js 401 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.36.2 compiled successfully in 730 ms
asset main.js 1010 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
cached modules 974 KiB [cached] 10 modules
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
./src/components/App.js 354 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.36.2 compiled successfully in 57 ms
```

Comment: I don't see react itself listed in your dependencies. Are any errors reported in your browser's console or in the terminal you are running the dev server? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: You open your question by saying your are trying to integrate with your django backend, but there's no sign of that here. Is your current problem just running a Hello, world app with the dev server as the code appears?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but aren't your NPM script "dev" simply building the files? Is it really starting a server listening on localhost as well?

Comment: @Quentin I added the html and what I see on my terminal when I type npm dev run. My current problem is just getting it to work with the simplest message before I integrate it.

Comment: @ViktorW According to the tutorial, I have to have both "npm dev run" and "python manage.py runserver" open but in the tutorial it works and for me it doesn't so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Okay so there's your server. If you open devtools (on chrome shift+ctrl+i) do you see anything in the console? Any errrors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"/>
> ```

The end tag for script elements is mandatory.

When the React dev server injects its `<script>` element into the page, it does so after the start tag for the above script element.

This means the browser treats it as the **content** of the script element and ignores it.

Write valid HTML.

(Also note that the React dev server isn't written in Python and doesn't understand the Django template language so it will not convert the template code you have into the URLs of your other JS and CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the App.js file .jsx and make sure you include appDiv and your index.js script file into your index.html.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice. I added the html where I included the main.js and the app but I'm not sure where I'm supposed to add the index.js to be honest.